# Ansible - How to get only certain parts of 'stdout_lines'?

Tags: ansible, freeipa

I run `ipa migrate-ds` command using Ansible.
When this command is finished I print out the result, which is similar to:

When `group:` is present in output:

```yaml
...
        "stdout_lines": [
            "-----------",
            "migrate-ds:",
            "-----------",
            "Migrated:",
            "  user: usr1,usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5",
            "  group: usr1, usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5",
            "Failed user:",
            "  admin: This entry already exists",
            ...
           ]
```

When `group:` is not present in output:

```yaml
  "stdout_lines": [
        "-----------",
        "migrate-ds:",
        "-----------",
        "Migrated:",
        "Failed user:",
        "  admin: This entry already exists",
         ...
        ]
```

I'm only interested in getting the groups under `group:` after `Migrated`, because I want to pass these to a script/template file.

It's important to note that sometimes `group:` is not even present in the `stdout_lines`, it all depends on the output of the command.

Comment: "_I run a command using Ansible._", can you provide the command and or task which is generating the output? Since "_sometimes `group:` is not even present in the `stdout_lines` nor is `Migrated:`, it all depends on the output of the command_", can you provide more output examples?

Comment: @U880D, I'll edit the intial post. Also it was incorrect from my side `Migrated:` is indeed visible regardless the outcome. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you get also *stdout* along with *stdout_lines*. Without the separators `-----------` *stdout* would be a valid YAML

```yaml
  stdout: |
    migrate-ds:
    Migrated:
      user: usr1,usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5
      group: usr1, usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5
    Failed user:
      admin: This entry already exists
```

Get rid of the separators and convert the string to YAML

```yaml
  data: "{{ stdout|from_yaml }}"
```

---

If you can't remove the separators from the output of the command use the filter [regex_replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_replace_filter.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-regex-replace-filter)

```yaml
data: "{{ stdout|regex_replace('^-+', '', multiline=True)|from_yaml }}"
```

---

gives

```yaml
  data:
    Failed user:
      admin: This entry already exists
    Migrated:
      group: usr1, usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5
      user: usr1,usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5
    migrate-ds: null
```

Comment: The separators are from the are outputs from `cmd` getting run.

Comment: @N.J, "_The separators are from the are outputs from `cmd` getting run._", maybe you can provide the command which is producing the output?

Comment: The command is `ipa migrate-ds`. @U880D

Comment: According [QA:Testcase FreeIPAv2 migration](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_freeipav2_migration) and other similar output from tools like `ldapsearch`, it seems one it left either with pre-processing the output or post-processing it since output formats are limited in those tools.

Comment: I've run @VladimirBotka example without success .

Comment: @U880D, did it help you?

Comment: @N.J, probably others, since it explains why the output looks like it is, why the command output can't be configured to be valid JSON upfront, etc. and more ...

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir's solution is probably better in this case, but if you're working with data that doesn't happen to be valid YAML you could also do something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sample_results:
      - "stdout_lines": [
          "-----------",
          "migrate-ds:",
          "-----------",
          "Migrated:",
          "  user: usr1,usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5",
          "  group: usr1, usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5",
          "Failed user:",
          "  admin: This entry already exists"
         ]
      - "stdout_lines": [
            "-----------",
            "migrate-ds:",
            "-----------",
            "Migrated:",
            "Failed user:",
            "  admin: This entry already exists"
            ]
  tasks:
    - loop: "{{ sample_results }}"
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            (
              item.stdout_lines | select('match', '  group:') | first | default("")
            ).split(': ')[1] | default("")
          }}
```

This uses the `select` filter to find the   `group:` line, and makes use of the `default` filter to handle the situation in which there is no   `group:` line in the output.

Running the above playbook produces:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'stdout_lines': ['-----------', 'migrate-ds:', '-----------', 'Migrated:', '  user: usr1,usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5', '  group: usr1, usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5', 'Failed user:', '  admin: This entry already exists']}) => {
    "msg": "usr1, usr2, usr3, usr4, usr5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'stdout_lines': ['-----------', 'migrate-ds:', '-----------', 'Migrated:', 'Failed user:', '  admin: This entry already exists']}) => {
    "msg": ""
}
```